# Help me identify this Marvel timeline/universe

Tags: marvel, avengers

This is only a brief question, as the information I have to go from is literally just this picture I stumbled on googling Marvel pics for my laptop background. The site hosting it was a dead end (just a random site with images- no info).

[image: 'Unknown Avengers?']

Now I'm familiar with a lot of story arcs/alternate timelines, but have never seen this and it looks awesome. At first I did think 'Marvel 1602' due to the style, but unless this is something that's newer (like Secret Wars) this looks more "swords & Sorcery" style to me, along with a few notable differences- Fury is the Samuel J version, Cap is known as Rojhaz and as far as my knowledge extends, 1602 is a "micro-verse" a self contained Earth in it's own dimension so has no links to Asgard at all?

I'm looking for any actual paper comic titles or story arcs that I may be able to hunt down for my collection. Its obviously an 'Avengers' title but I can not ever recall seeing this in my local shop.

Comment: You could have easily solved this yourself by using http://images.google.com .

Comment: A google search would've gone a long way.....

Comment: Well all I can say to that is- Im obviously not as computer savvy as some- and didn't even know this was possible (until now). I still believe my question was valid though at the time, I never understand the down voting on this site sometimes- I'm getting down voted because of some software I was unaware of, not because the question? lol.

Comment: I like this question, and have wiped out the rogue downvote accordingly :-)

Comment: Thankyou @maguirenumber6. I have to say that (without knowing you could google pictures) the "Marvel" logo is what really sold me on the artwork as a legit picture and not some fan made homage. I would love to read something that looks like this though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is a set of fan drawn pictures by artist DURRRRIAN. [It can be seen here.](http://thedurrrrian.deviantart.com/gallery/?catpath=%2F&q=avengers)